# Regex based replace in js

Tags: javascript, regex

actually I want to replace a string except if it comes in a round bracket.

For example:

```
JAVA is a nice language. (JAVA) has lots of features. JAVA is portable. (JAVA) even comes in 64 bit.
```

now if i replace JAVA with C:

then desired output is :

```
C is a nice language. (JAVA) has lots of features. C is portable. (JAVA) even comes in 64 bit.
```

even java can come as a sub string like

```
 XJAVAX is a nice language. (XJAVAX) has lots of features. JAVA is portable. (JAVA) even comes in 64 bit.
```

now if i replace JAVA by C :

Then expected output :

```
XCX is a nice language. (XJAVAX) has lots of features. C is portable. (JAVA) even comes in 64 bit.
```

Comment: Please don't replace Java with C, please...

Comment: it's just an example..i din't really mean it..I hope u r confused..I would suggest u 2 leave s/w industry and join some .....

Comment: I think that those whose upvoted the comment @Mudassir understood the stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JavaScript doesn't have look-behind, the easiest way is probably an alternation:

```
str = str.replace(/\(JAVA\)|JAVA/g, function(m) {
    return m === "(JAVA)" ? m : "C";
    // Or
    // return m.length === 6 ? m : "C";
});
```

Beyond that, you get into trying to [simulate look-behind](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), which is possible in some ways, but messy.

Comment: @Neel: That's probably easily addressed by putting a word boundary marker on either side of the alternation: `\b\(JAVA\)|JAVA\b`. Running out the door so I couldn't test that. The [MDC page on RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) can be a useful guide. The [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10) has all the details, but it's not as readable.